# My web server and Android communication

Tags: php, android, webserver

I have a web page that is a demo for a web shop, which I will implement later. In the web shop you can select an item to buy it. In my demo scenario, I just want to send the info about the cost of the item to my Android upon button click in the web shop.

**STEP-BY-STEP explanation:**

1. openWebShop (in Android app you click a button and it calls this method to open URI)
2. Web Shop opens with items that you can buy.
3. Select an item from the list
4. onItemClick send the prize value and name of item selected to the Android device and store it in a String
5. Close WebShop -> display your App again with a New Intent / Fragment displaying the chosen Item name and Prize tag.

I also want to upload some files to the web shop. There are some questions here on Stack Overflow on how to do that, but for the time being, I won't tackle that problem yet.

**QUESTIONS:**

- Can I use GCM for my idea ?
- Do I need to create a Web page apart from Android coding or can you style your web shop inside Android coding? (no experience with web development)
- Do I need to implement a onItemSelected inside PHP or is it done somehow else?

**SOME INFO I GOT:**

What I have learned so far is that I could use HTTP request to download a file from Web Server. I only saw examples on how to download XML files, but I assume that is the same for any file type. But I am not sure whether if this is the best solution for my case. I noticed GCM, but have trouble with PHP, since I have no experience with it - does it have some sort of onClick method ?

Comment: Are you wanting your app to communicate with the web? If so it sounds like you need an API - search for "Android API PHP" for examples (and just watch out for tutorials with security problems).

Comment: Basically yes. I am now reading about Java Servlets, it might be a good thing for what I need to do for this demo. I just need to create a simple web shop to demonstrate the communication between Android and the Web Shop (if a customer picks an item, App will get the Item name and Cost).

Comment: Servlets will do it (and you know Java already), so yes, give it a go. PHP would be fine too, it depends what you like working with. Unfortunately this topic is rather too broad for Stack Overflow, as interesting as it is. Your best approach would be to get into the coding and ask a focussed question if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your information though. I will try to implement it with Java Servlets, hence I have knowledge of Java. Will return here with more specific question if I'll encounter problems!

Comment: @halfer me again. I was wondering if there is a different solution to this other than Servlets ? Since I'm using Android Studio, and Servlets require Eclipse, it gets a bit messy for me. I am looking at GCM (Google Cloud Messaging), can I download files from my Web Server with that? Or is it just for messaging?

Comment: I don't know GCM, so can't speak about that. But you can build an API in any server-side technology - it is just a machine-readable website. PHP, Python, Ruby, JavaScript, Java, Scala, probably Go... use whatever you are most comfortable with.

Comment: @halfer It's obvious to me that I really lack knowledge of Server-Side technology. If you'd be kind enough to give me some links on Tutorials / Explanations / Literature to this, I'd appreciate it very much  For e.g. PHP or JavaScript

Comment: I've searched for a couple in PHP, and they all seem to have security holes in - I wouldn't be helping if I recommended them. I wonder if you might be better off getting a book! Use "REST" and "RESTful" as your search engine terms.

Comment: OK, [this is not awful](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json) even though the database library is now deprecated.